# Reduced matrices and conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $S$ be a $d^2 \times d^2$ matrix given by
$$S |ij\rangle = \lambda_{ji} |ij\rangle$$
for $\lambda_{ji}\in \mathbb{C}$ and $|\lambda_{ji} | =1$. We can write a matrix $d\times d$ matrix $U$ from the elements of $S$ as follows:
$$U^i_j = \lambda_{ij}.$$
I have the condition that $\text{det}(U) = 0$, but I'm wondering how to relate this to $S$ in a meaningful way. Clearly this condition is a condition on the elements of $S$ by construction, but for large $d$ is a very cumbersome one. I have considered related $U$ to the partial trace of $S$, but this didn't seem to match up. Investigating eigenvalues also didn't seem to be helpful.

Comment: I believe that one conclusion you can reach using this information is that $S$ can be expressed as a sum
$$
S = \sum_{j=1}^k A_j \otimes B_j
$$
with $k \leq d-1$ where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product and $A_j,B_j$ each $d \times d$. I don't know if this is equivalent to your condition.

Comment: More generally, the rank of the matrix $[\lambda_{ij}]_{i,j}$ gives you an upper bound for the minimal integer $k$ required for such an expression

Comment: Taking that slightly further, I believe if we define the tensor flip by $F|ij\rangle  = |ji\rangle$ then this should imply $$S = F\sum_{j=1}^k A_j \otimes B_j$$ where  $A_j$ and $B_j$ are diagonal matrices. I'm a little unsure as to how you conclude this is finite though. Would you mind expanding please?

Comment: This also suggests (I think) that if $B_j = B$ for all $j$, then $U$ is has always unit rank, and hence zero determinant. I may be off with a tensor flip, so I may mean $A_j =A$ for all $j$, but the implication the same.

Comment: The fact that $\lambda_{ij}$ has rank at most $d-1$ means that there are $d-1$ pairs of vectors $a^1,b^1,\dots,a^{k},b^k$ such that
$$
\lambda_{ij} = \sum_{p=1}^k a^p_{i}b^p_j.
$$
Thus, $S$ is the sum of the maps $A^p \otimes B^p$, where 
$$
A^p |i\rangle = a^p_i, \quad B^p |j \rangle = b^p_j \implies 
(A^p \otimes B^p) |ij \rangle = a^p_ib^p_j |ij \rangle.
$$